# Upper Limit Reddit, Tumblr and Livejournal RSS Feed Results?

Tags: rss, tumblr, reddit

I am aware of this syntax to get around the default 25 items limit when subscribing to Reddit RSS feeds:

> http://reddit.com/r/[subreddit].rss?limit=[limit]

My question is, is there an upper limit on "limit"? For example, if I put in, say 500, would I get 500 items each time the feed updated or does Reddit just have a number which you can't exceed for "limit"?

Similarly, is there such syntax for subscribing to Tumblr and LiveJournal feeds, to get around whatever the default setting is? If so, is there an upper limit?

Thanks!

Comment: The limit it determined by each sites API, like mentioned below.

Comment: I get that, but I am having trouble navigating said APIs. If someone could post a link to the actually API entry for those services concerning RSS, that would be helpful.

Comment: Obviously I Google'd it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of the RSS spec in any way I would not expect that to work with Tumblr or LiveJournal. Actually, I would not expect that to work beyond Reddit...

Comment: I know that. My question was basically how many RSS items can you get for each service, and how do you do it (aside from Reddit, which I clearly know how to do).

Comment: It really depends on the service. Based on our experience at Superfeedr, the average is between 10 and 20. Few services go beyond 50. Usually, you can only get the feeds that are in the feed as 99.99% of feeds don't support pagination/count.

Comment: You aren't answering my question. My question is not "how does RSS work?" it is "does anyone know the specific number for these specific services I listed and do these services support pagination/count and if so, how?".

Comment: Look it up! It's fairly easy: download a Tumblr feed, count its entries. Repeat with LiveJournal. They do not support pagination/count.

Comment: I already did that, I was asking if it supported pagination/count and if so, to what degree, but you ended up answering my question anyway.